# Orthogonal projection to perspective projection MCP

Tags: java

I am trying to code a mod for "Minecraft". I used the method "setupOverlayRendering" that changed the projection to orthogonal. I did this because I need to render text on screen. While the text is rendering I need to render a line, using perspective projection.

```
                    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
                    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
                    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
                    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
```

I am using this code to revert the projection to perspective.

Comment: And...? I assume something isn't working or you wouldn't have posted the question, but it's not at all clear (to me at least) what's not working, and what it's doing or not doing vs. what you want it to do.

Comment: It's not going back to Perspective projection.